# What island in the Caspian sea did Ala Ad-Din Muhammad die on, after escaping Genghis Khan?

Tags: 13th-century, mongol-empire

At the end of the invasion of Khwarezmia Empire, Genghis Khan chased [Ala Ad-Din Muhammad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad_II_of_Khwarezm) to the Caspian sea, where he hid on an island and died several weeks later. However, none of the sources I can find ever mention the actual island that he died on.

I've always been curious since as far as I know there are not too many islands to speak of in the Caspian sea. The only real information I can find is that it was an Island close to the port of Abaskun.

What is the island and does it still exist today?

Answer (score 8):

Well, there are two problems - the first is that we don't know where [Abaskun](http://www.iranicaonline.org/articles/abaskun) actually is. It was purported to be in the area of the mouth of the Gorgan River, which brings us to another issue - there are numerous sandbars in the region, which come and go with the weather over a span of years. The "island" may have been a vegetated sandbar (also known as a barrier island) that has since been subsumed by the sea, after a storm or a flood or just centuries of erosion, forever lost. No-one knows exactly where the island is, or even if it still exists.

Comment: +1 from me. I zoomed the google map in on some of the river mouths. I never did see an island, but there are some roads that extend out into the lake, with marks for resteraunts at the end of them. I'm guessing there are lots of little islands in there google's topography isn't up to showing. No telling which one it would be.

Answer (score 2):

I can't find exactly where the port of Abaskun was, but it is said to be near modern Gorgun, which is near the southeast corner of the Caspian Sea.

All I see on [Google Maps in that area](http://maps.google.com/maps?q=gorgan&rls=com.microsoft%3aen-us&oe=UTF-8&startIndex=&startPage=1&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&sa=N&tab=wl) is a couple of barrier islands (one of which technically you could claim is a peninsula). So most likely it would have been one of those. The larger one paralleling the southern coast is named Ashoorzadeh Island, the smaller one paralleling the east coast Google doesn't name.

Comment: The barrier island/peninsula looks like it is man-made.

Comment: @Luke - Does it? In what way? I know the Atlantic and Gulf coasts of the USA are replete with similar-looking barrier islands, which I believe are quite natural. For instance, South Padre in Texas and Okaloosa ( http://maps.google.com/maps?rls=com.microsoft:en-us&oe=UTF-8&startIndex=&startPage=1&q=okaloosa+island&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hq=&hnear=0x88913ea0b298a663:0xf03dd12bb7242e35,Okaloosa+Island,+Fort+Walton+Beach,+FL&gl=us&sa=X&ei=BZgiUKsXgZ7YBa69gYgK&ved=0CIYBELYD ) in Florida.

Comment: Well, I could be persuaded either way, but that was my first take on it.